# In D&D 4e, are 1/2 level defense bonuses compound with the raised ability modifier?

Tags: dnd-4e, defense

I've recently started playing D&D with some friends, and the one thing on the character sheet that bothers me is the defense section.

In the defenses section, it has both the sections 10 + 1/2 Lvl and Ability Modifier parts. 
I would assume that you would take 10 + 1/2 Lvl + Ability Modifier as your bonus, where your ability modifier isn't also raised by half level, because you're already adding it to the ten. Simply speaking, if I had a level two Paladin with 16 strength, my fortitude would be: 10 + 1 + 3 = 14 (neglecting other bonuses) and not 10 + 1 + (3 + 1) = 15 (again, neglecting other bonuses) because my ability modifier is also being raised by 1/2 level. Is this correct?

If not, then I would feel exceedingly stupid for being smacked around unnecessarily by monsters :P

(Also, if someone could clarify on whether AC is armor + ability score only when you're wearing light armor or not, that would be great. Thanks!)

Comment: A key distinction on the character sheet is that Mod is simply stat - 10 divided by 2 (round down) whereas check is mod + level/2 (round down). The check number is basically only used for skill checks when you don't have a relevant skill associated with what you are trying to do. Basically everything else (defenses, to-hit bonus, damage bonus) are factored off the plain, old, regular mod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your logic is correct!**

Yes in 4E for your defenses you add 10+relevant ability modifier+ 1/2 your level rounded down + any relevant class bonuses.

You only add half your level once. Oh and welcome to the site!

And yes your AC is armor + ability modifier only when you wear light to no armor.

Comment: A predicate is incorrect (Ability Modifiers are static and do not increase by level), so the logic cannot be correct, though the result is.

Comment: @Xabei they are not static... The increase every 4 levels...

Comment: @ Jonn_Underwood They are static, in the sense that they are tied to the Ability score. It is the Abilities that increase every 3-4 levels (and not all of them at all intervals), and when they do, they may drag the mod along.

Comment: @ Jonn_Underwood ... But then, if we account for this, then your answer is incorrect, as these  increases are to be included in the calculus as part of the mod.